# Wildcard Character in String

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet I receive regularly with a large number of cells containing names. Some cells have a full name including a middle initial with a period.

For example:

> Springer, Jerry A.

Every now and then though the sheet I receive will have the following:

> Springer, Jerry .

I need to get rid of those middle initials but also check to make sure that I just delete the "." if it's there.

Forgive me for my lack of proper logic, but I have the following ca-ca sub:

```
Sub DeleteMiddleI()
Dim nr1, nr2 As Range
Dim col As Integer

col = 1
Set nr1 = Cells(65536, col).End(xlUp)
Set nr2 = Cells(col, 1)

Do While nr2 <> nr1
    'Check to be sure the cell isn't empty
    If Len(nr2) <> 0 Then
         'Check to see if the last character is a "."
         If Right$(nr2, 1) = "." Then
            'Check and be sure there is a character before the "."
            If InStr(1, nr2.Text, "[A-Z].") > 0 Then '<<<<<<CODE BREAKAGE
                nr2 = Left$(nr2, Len(nr2) - 3)
            End If
         End If
    End If

    col = col + 1
    Set nr2 = Cells(col, 1)
Loop

End Sub
```

It breaks on the

> If InStr(1, nr2.Text, "[A-Z].") > 0 Then

I feel stupid...but what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this help? This would replace all the " ." with nothing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:=" .", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

What did you mean by removing initials part? Do you mean changing `Springer, Jerry A.` to `Springer, Jerry` or `Springer, Jerry .` to `Springer, Jerry`

If yes, then would this help?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Pos As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            Pos = InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, ", ") + 2
            If Pos > 2 Then
                Pos = InStr(Pos, .Range("A" & i).Value, " ")
                If Pos > 0 Then .Range("A" & i).Value = Mid(.Range("A" & i).Value, 1, Pos - 1)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're suggestion of taking "Springer, Jerry A." and also "Springer, Jerry ." to "Springer, Jerry" is exactly what I'm striving to accomplish. I'll test this code and see if I can get it working. Thank you.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Siddharth Rout

Comment: The above can be achieved with a formula as well :)

Comment: If the name is in Cell A1 then you can use this formula in cell B1 `=IF(ISERROR(MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(", ",A1,1)+2))),A1,MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(", ",A1,1)+2)))`

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the if test from:

```
If Right$(nr2, 1) = "." Then
```

to

```
If (Right$(nr2, 1) = "." AND Left$(nr2, 1) <> "." ) Then
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it still will delete part of a name in the format "Last, First ."; That will become "Last, Firs", instead of "Last, First" like I'm trying to find. Thank you though for the help